# Alert user to unsaved changes on page before closing the page. Rails 6. Updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, jquery-dirtyforms

Updated to use smarter implementation (or at least briefer). This will make most of the comments irrelevant, but thank you for those comments.

**How to alert user to unsaved changes on page before closing the page.** Rails 6.

[AreYouSure](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure) added via `yarn add areyousure`.

Relevant in `application.js`

```
import 'jquery';
global.$ = global.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
import 'areyousure/areyousure.js';
```

In `/edit.html.erb`, `data-areyousure` added to div surrounding form

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" data-areyousure >
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't even allow any changes to the form. As soon as you click in the form the edit page updates to `Are you sure? Yes | No`. Not a popup.

Not seeing much activity on the [github](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure/issues) page.

[Demo (link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511230426/http://www.papercut.com/products/free_software/are-you-sure/demo/are-you-sure-demo.html) on github is dead). Tried [dirtyforms](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms) too. Had other issues. Seems like I'm closer with AreYouSure

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are targeting the `div` container around your form, instead of the form itself. Try attaching `areyousure` to the form object:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Edit Person') %>
<h1>Edit: <%= @person.full_name %></h1>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#person_edit_form form').areyousure(
      {
        message: 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
               + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.'
      }
    );
  });
</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="person_edit_form">
    <!-- !render bookmark -->
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ryan Crispin Heneise Thank you for the suggestion, but still the same problem. I should add that when I try to do anything in edit a new edit page pops up with the default warning. Not just a pop up. I just checked my people_controller and def edit has nothing. I tried putting the div id deeper in the form and still have the same problem (can't edit), so I'm thinking there is an error in the JavaScript or some other deeper conflict.

Comment: Try checking the capitalization of that method name - in the docs it is written as `areYouSure()`, but you wrote `areyousure()`.

Comment: It's lowercase because of `import 'areyousure/areyousure.js';`. Added via yarn and I'm almost positive that is the way it needs to be or it wouldn't be doing anything. But just to be sure I put in `areYouSure` and nothing happens. I checked something else when it goes to the edit page when I try to edit. The page has the title and `Are you sure? Yes | No` which is the default, not the message in the script. Nothing in the server logs or console.